# How to know if the uploaded file has been changed?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload, file-io

If the user uploads some file to my server and I want to make sure that the file hasn't been changed from the last time the user uploaded it, how can I get this information?

I have a log table with `User_id` and `FileName` (the `User_id` is unique). I delete the file after I read the contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of the file before deleting it. To see if it is the same file being uploaded, compare the hash with the previous hash. You can do this with one of the HashAlgorithm classes in System.Cryptography, such as [SHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx).

> "A cryptographic hash function is a deterministic procedure that takes
>   an arbitrary block of data and returns a fixed-size bit string, the
>   (cryptographic) hash value, such that an accidental or intentional
>   change to the data will change the hash value"

Here is some example code to get you started, assuming the variable `stream` is a stream with your file data (you could use `FileStream` to open it):

```
var sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
byte [] hash = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
```

Now, the variable `hash` will contain the hash, a fingerprint of the file contents. Even a small change (such as a single bit) will result in a different hash value, but taking the hash on the same file will always return the same hash.

Comment: How to do store a hash of the file? and if the user changes the contents , Did this change the hash of the file?

Comment: Yes, even a change of 1 byte of data, half of the bits in the hash change. The hash algorithms are designed to be so.

Comment: If i remember I face the following exception some times when i hash some data .`Invalid length for a Base-64 char array`

Comment: What is the best algorthim in my case and how to avoid this exception?

Comment: base64 has nothing to do with the hashing, but in some cases it can be practical to store the hash encoded in base64. I updated with an example.

Comment: You don't need to worry too much about picking the "right" hash algorithm for this, all of the hash classes in System.Security.Cryptography is sufficient, if you only need to know if the file changes. SHA1 or another of the SHA variants is a common choice. If this was for security purposes, picking the right algorithm would be more important.

Comment: Thank us so much. one more question , Does it take time (performance wise) to hash a large file?

Comment: Yes, it does take some time to calculate the hash.

Comment: A less performance intensive way of doin it would be to use the `FileInfo` class and compare the `LastWriteTime` with the date you uploaded it (from a DB or wherever). There are tradeoffs as the LastWriteTime (date modified) can be altered without the file contents changing and also the file contents can change and the date modified be "reset" to before the change. It's worth considerin if it doesn't put your site's file integrity at risk.

Comment: @ PunkyGuy: thanks a lot i think about this method but i fail.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285733/how-to-get-the-last-modified-date-of-the-uploaded-file

Answer (score 3):

Hash is the generic kind of function. Usually to detect changes into large chunks of data, like files, is used some [crc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)

Under linux there is the standard utility [cksum](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cksum)

You can spawn a **cksum *filename*** and grab the output. Store it, for example in your database, and check on new file incoming.