# How to get Creation date for Kendo Upload

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am use Kendo Upload, 
how to get creation date a file?

```
    function onUpload(e) {
         e.files //I can get modified date only
    }
```

anyone can help me to get creation date by using kendo or normal jquery?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is never sent to the server when you use a file input to upload a file. Only the filename, mime type and contents are sent with multipart/form-data. You could use the HTML5 File API to obtain this information from the file before uploading it.

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285733/how-to-get-the-last-modified-date-of-the-uploaded-file) on details.

Comment: thank you for the answer. i got it. i can use uploadify to enable grab creation date.